# event.preventDefault() on first click then remove

Tags: jquery

I have the default anchor disabled if it has a class subnav as shown in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/5Quee/).

I only want this disabled for the first click then I want the normal anchor functionality to be brought back.  What is the best way to do this?  I tried something involving the below code but this didn't seem to work?

```
  $(this).unbind(event.preventDefault());
```

maybe something like this psuedo code?

```
if (click count === 0 ) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

or is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass `false` to [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/):

```
$(".subnav a").one("click", false);
```

Passing `false` instead of a handler is equivalent to passing a handler that returns `false`, effectively stopping the event's propagation and preventing its default behavior.

This is explained in the documentation for [bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/):

> In jQuery 1.4.3 you can now pass in `false` in place of an event
>   handler. This will bind an event handler equivalent to: `function() {
>   return false; }`.

Comment: This is much simpler than what I had thanks.  For the record I used $("ul > .subnav > a").one("click", false); so that it would only affect that level and not children.

Comment: Check this out http://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/ in theory it sounds ideal but when I tried this I had to double-click to get the click event to fire :-/

Answer (score 10):

This works well.  The second click goes to the page...

```
$(".smallNavigation > ul > li > a").click(function (e) {

    $("ul.sub-menu").hide();
    $("ul.sub-menu", $(this).parent("li")).show();

    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).unbind(e);

}
```

Comment: this helped me! specifically. `e.preventDefault();
    $(this).unbind(e); ` thanks

Answer (score 9):

Bind the event handler with `one()`[<sup>docu</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/one/). It executes once and automatically unbinds itself afterwards.

```
$(".subnav a").one("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Alternatively you can unbind it yourself directly in the function. It's good to use a namespace for that

```
$(".subnav a").bind("click.myclick", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).unbind(".myclick");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something as simple as self unbind in the click handler.

Something like

```
function stopEventOnce(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).unbind('click',stopEventOnce);
  return false;
}
$(".subnav a").bind('click', stopEventOnce);
```

[Modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sujay/5Quee/2/)

Answer (score 0):

this will work for you

```
$("#elementid").bind("click", function( event ) {
  alert("This will be displayed only once.");
  event.preventDefault(); 
  $(this).unbind( event );
});
```