# Prevent body scrolling on iPhone when fullscreen overlay opened

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, iphone

I'm trying to prevent the body from being scrollable when my fullscreen overlay nav is opened. I have applied a class `show-nav` to body with attributes `overflow: hidden` and it works well on the desktop but it doesn't seem to work on the iPhone.

So after reading similar questions on stackoverflow I tried using `e.preventDefault()`, which works, but the body will still remain unscrollable when the nav is closed, how do I reenable scrolling when the nav is closed?

```
    $( "button.navbar-toggle" ).on( "click", function(e) {
     $('body').on('touchmove', function (e) {
              e.preventDefault();
     });
      $('html').toggleClass('show-nav');
      $('body').toggleClass('show-nav');
    });
```

Comment: You might want to try $(this).unbind(e); on your closing function. You can read about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11772926/event-preventdefault-on-first-click-then-remove).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Tim for getting me in the right direction: here's what works for me:

```
    // On nav opens toggle show-nav class to html/body (overflow: hidden to prevent scroll on desktop) + disable scroll on mobile
    $( "button.navbar-toggle#open-nav" ).on( "click", function(e) {
      $('body').bind('touchmove', function(e){e.preventDefault()});
      $('html').toggleClass('show-nav');
      $('body').toggleClass('show-nav');
    });
    // On nav close toggle show-nav class to html/body (overflow: hidden to prevent scroll on desktop) + enable scroll on mobile        
    $( "button.navbar-toggle#close-nav" ).on( "click", function(e) {
      $('body').unbind('touchmove');
      $('html').toggleClass('show-nav');
      $('body').toggleClass('show-nav');
    });
    // Clicking on any link will close nav  + enable scroll on mobile
    $('.site-nav ul.nav li').on("click", function(e) {
      $('body').unbind('touchmove');
      $('html').toggleClass('show-nav');
      $('body').toggleClass('show-nav');
    });
```

Hope it helps others experiencing the same issue :) Cheers!